# Is it possible to work out the Fourier series of $\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x)$ without knowing the positive integers $m$ and $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

For instance, let $m$ be an odd number. Then the Fourier series of $\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x)$ have forms like $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}b_k \sin(kx)$. Next, we can get $b_k$ through the integral
$$\displaystyle b_k = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \sin^m(x)\cos^n(x)\sin(kx) \mathrm{d}x$$
However, I find it too hard to compute. Even though I use formulas like
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^p(x)\cos^q(x) \mathrm{d} x=\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{q+1}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{p+q}{2}+1\right)}$$
and
$$\displaystyle\sin(kx)=\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac{k-1}{2}]}(-1)^j\binom{k}{2j+1}\cos^{k-2j-1}(x)\sin^{2j+1}(x)$$
I still get a bulk of sums and factorials:
$$\displaystyle b_k = \dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{k+n+m}{2}-3}}\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac{k-1}{2}]}(-1)^j\dfrac{k!(m+2j)!!(k+n-2j-2)!!}{(2j+1)!(k-2j-1)!\left(\frac{k+n+m}{2}\right)!}, \text{ when } n \text{ and } k \text{ are not both odd or even}$$
$$b_k = 0, \text{ when } n \text{ and } k \text{ are both odd or even}$$
What's worse, I can't even get $b_k = 0$ when $k>m+n$ through this way, which should theoretically hold. I am not familiar with skills of calculating factorials so I can only use computer programs to check $b_k = 0$ when $k>m+n$.

Is it possible to work out the Fourier series of $\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x)$ without knowing the positive integers $m$ and $n$?

Answer (score 2):

If you know a bit of complex analysis you can use the residue theorem for [calculating trigonometric integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_3_%E2%80%93_trigonometric_integrals).
I will use the bases of complex exponentials
$$
I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin^m(x)\cos^n(x) e^{ikx} dx=\frac{1}{2^{m+n} i^{m+1}}\int_C \frac{(z^2-1)^m (z^2+1)^n }{z^{m+n+1-k}} dz
$$
Notice that if $k\ge m+n+1$ it is the integral of an holomorphic function and so it is zero

For all the other values of $k$ the integral is evaluated as
$$
\frac{\pi}{2^{m+n-1}i^m(m+n-k)!} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d^{m+n-k}}{dz} (z^2-1)^m (z^2+1)^n 
$$
As the degree of the polynomial is  $2(m+n)$ if $k\le -(m+n+1)$ the residue is zero.

Moreover as the polynomial has only terms of even degree, if $m+n-k$ is odd the residue is zero (we are taking the limit for $z\to0$).

You have

$$
(z^2-1)^m (z^2+1)^n =\left(\sum_{i=0}^m (-1)^{m-i}\binom{m}{i} z^{2i}\right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} z^{2j}\right)
$$
By using the (finite) [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), calculating the derivative and the limit we obtain
$$
I=\frac{\pi}{2^{m+n-1} i^m} \sum_{\substack{l_1+l_2=\frac{m+n-k}{2}\\l_1 \le m, \ \ l_2 \le n}} (-1)^{m-l_1} \binom{m}{l_1} \binom{n}{l_2}
$$
for $-(m+n+1) < k < m+n+1$ such that $k$ has the same parity w.r.t. $m+n$

If you want the expansion to be in the bases of $(\sin(kx),\cos(kx))$ you can then proceed as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239134/fourier-series-and-exponential)

Comment: I think you should add "For all other values..." before the paragraph that starts with "The value of the integral is given by.." Other than that (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^m(x) \cos^n(x)$ = $(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i})^m$ $(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2})^n$=

$$\frac{1}{(2i)^m (2)^n}(\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k}e^{ikx}(-1)^{m-k}e^{-i(m-k)x}) \times   (\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}e^{inx}e^{-i(n-k)x})$$

you can simplify it further and this is how you find the fourier series and with this method you can calculate the integral.